# Splitting a list of lists in specific intervals in Python

Tags: python, list, split

I have a really big list of lists with integers that is also sorted from low to high. Also every nested list is an arithmetic sequence increasing by 1 . To make it more clear it could look something like:

```
f = [[0,1], [3], [7,8,9,10,11,12], [15,16], [18], [22,23,24], [39,40,41], [49,50,51]]
```

My goal is to split the nested big list into smaller nested lists. My first list must have numbers between 0 and 10, my second list must have numbers between 20 and 30 , my third between 40 to 50 etc. So I was wondering if there is a way to code in python to get the following lists:

```
f1 = [[0,1],[3],[7,8,9,10]]
f2 = [[22,23,24]]
f3 = [[40,41],[49,50]]
```

Comment: in what list should `[17,18,19,20,21,22]` be?

Comment: What happened to 11 and 12 in your first sub list? They went to the next sub list ?

Comment: interestingly there are no lists for 10 to 20 and 30 to 40 so those values probably get thrown out?

Comment: @NicolasTabet I am sorry for not being clear enough. I want every interval from (10,20), (30,40) etc to get thrown out. So the [17,18,19] would be thrown out and f2 would be f2 = [[20,21,22], [22,23,24]]

Comment: @SorousHBakhtiary they get thrown out, sry for not clearing that up. I want only values between [0,10], [20,30], [40,50], [60,70] and so on. I dont want (10,20), (30,40), (50,60), (70,80) and so on

Comment: @Matiiss Exactly!!!It's like I am keeping ten, I discard ten, I am keeping ten , I discard ten. I want intervals [0,10], [20,30], [40,50] and so on but not (10,20), (30,40), (50,60) and so on

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do so:

```
data = []
for i in range(0, f[-1][-1], 20):
    new_seqs = []
    for seq in f:
        if i - len(seq) + 1 <= seq[0] <= i + 10:
            new_nums = []
            for num in seq:
                if i <= num <= i + 10:
                    new_nums.append(num)
            new_seqs.append(new_nums)
    data.append(new_seqs)
print(data)
```

The same using list comprehension:

```
data = [[[num for num in seq if i <= num <= i + 10] for seq in f if i - len(seq) + 1 <= seq[0] <= i + 10] for i in range(0, f[-1][-1], 20)]
print(data)
```

**Output:**

```
[[[0, 1], [3], [7, 8, 9, 10]], [[22, 23, 24]], [[40, 41], [49, 50]]]
```

---

- We run a for loop from 0 to the largest element in the list (`f[-1][-1]`), increasing by 20 each time.
- For each sub-list we check if at least one element is included between `i` and `i + 10`. As it is an arithmetic sequence of common difference 1, we only have to compare the first term.
- If there is at least one term in the interval, we compare each number with `i` and `i + 10`.

Comment: I guess everyone goes through the phase of just pushing Python's one-liners to the limits... did it have to be a one-liner list comprehension? it is extremely unreadable but I guess that doesn't matter because it is a one-liner and that's what matters... don't worry I have been there, it feels pretty great putting it all in one line, mashing code together in a language where indentation matters a lot, but readability for these massive one-liners sucks

Comment: @Matiiss You're definitely right, it's literally unreadable and doesn't improve the code in any way. Thank you for this reminder :)

Comment: but it looks kind of cool though, even if the only reason for that is because it is on one line

Answer (score 0):

I guess, similar to this is what you are looking for?

```
from collections import defaultdict
mem = defaultdict(list)
# expectations: each sub-list  is stickly between x * 10 and (x+1) * 10 where x is a number

def find_list_number(num, i=10):
  if num < i:
    return int(i / 10)
  else:
    return find_list_number(num, i + 10)


for sub_list in flist:
  my_max = max(sub_list)
  key = find_list_number(my_max)
  mem[key].append(sub_list)

for k, v in mem.items():
  print((k, v))
```

Sample Output for above

```sh
(1, [[0, 1], [3]])
(2, [[7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], [15, 16], [18]])
(3, [[22, 23, 24]])
(5, [[39, 40, 41]])
(6, [[49, 50, 51]])
```

Note: `[7,8,9,10,11,12]` is in different class - not bug here. But you can modify conditions as you need & add additional conditions as it suits you. This is a sample, only to guide you.

Comment: The output is not matched to the OP's expected output.

Comment: @SorousHBakhtiary - Tx for checking. I added `expectation` in the code as well as `Note` for the same reason. Requester need to sort out his rules. I only share sample code of how to sort sublist into separate buckets. If you suggest, I will delete this answer.